# Cann't see the changes made in View without stopping the running application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have Visual studio 2022 . in order to view any changes that I make through view or css or everywhere, I should I have stop and Start Running MVC application ( I mean the green trinagle in toolbar).I mean if I referesh the browser, the changes will not be effected until I stop and run it again. how can I be able to view the changes without stopping the visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS2022 Community.

If you are using MVC with Razor views, do the following:
Install the package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation' if its not already included in your dependencies.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

In Program.cs, look for the line:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Change it to:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```